# How can I add using html() function jquery

Tags: html, jquery, dom

How can I add both itemName and itemPrice to a HTML element. It seems itemName is not showing up because itemPrice is taking priority. Sorry seems like a silly question but cannot figure it out.

```
const parent_id = $(this).parent().parent();
const itemName= parent_id[0].querySelector("h4");
const itemPrice = parent_id[0].querySelector("span");
const itemImage= parent_id[0].querySelector("img");

$(".test-div").html(itemName);
$(".test-div").html(itemPrice);
```

Comment: `$(".test-div").append(itemPrice);`

Comment: From https://api.jquery.com/html/ `.html(object)` isn't an intended use of `.html(string)` - so you could also do `$(".test-div").html(itemName + itemPrice)` if `itemName = $(parent_id[0],querySelector("h4")).html();` (or other way to get itemName as html without the convoluted mixing of jquery and DOM methods)